# Dynamic Keybind Without Use of Macro

Tags: spacemacs, elisp-macros

I've attempted to make a function which binds the leader keys `o f` to switch to the current buffer:

```
(defmacro bind-current-file ()
  (list 'spacemacs/set-leader-keys
        "of"
        (list 'lambda
              ()
              (list 'interactive)
              (list 'find-file (buffer-file-name)))))
```

This function works perfectly, except it can't be called interactively (since apparently emacs doesn't allow for macros to be called interactively).

Is there some workaround to achieve this?

Comment: I do a similar thing in my config, except I just use a function and it works fine (and can be called interactively). Is there a reason why you prefer a macro?

Comment: Don't define a macro when a function will do...

Comment: @randouser Because `(buffer-file-name)` needs to be evaluated at the time the keybinding is made, instead of at the time the keyboard shortcut is called.  AFAIK this requires a macro. Or am I wrong?

Comment: George, you should add that rationale to the question. It wasn’t obvious at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of other options. With lexical bindings, you could do this:

```
(defun bind-current-file ()
  (let (the-file (buffer-file-name))
    (spacemacs/set-leader-keys "of"
      (lambda ()
        (interactive)
        (find-file the-file)))))
```

Or you could use a dynamic variable:

```
(defvar the-file nil)
(spacemacs/set-leader-keys "of"
  (lambda ()
    (interactive)
    (find-file the-file)))
(defun bind-current-file ()
  (setq the-file (buffer-file-name)))
```

I don’t use spacemacs, so I didn’t actually test these; YMMV.

You should take the time to read [chapter 12.10 Scoping Rules for Variable Bindings](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Variable-Scoping.html) of the Emacs Lisp manual, which goes into some detail about both dynamic and lexical bindings.

Edit: I should point out that you have to opt in to lexical bindings; put `; -*- mode: emacs-lisp; lexical-binding: t -*-` at the top of your file.

Comment: The second solution works. The first solution yields the error "Symbol’s value as variable is void: the-file" when the keyboard shortcut is fired.

Comment: Sounds like you forgot to actually enable lexical bindings; it’s not the default. Go back and read chapter 12.10.4 Using Lexical Binding of the Elisp manual as well as chapter 49.2.4.1 Specifying File Variables of the Emacs manual and then add `; -*- mode: emacs-lisp; lexical-binding: t -*-` to the top of your init file.

Comment: Sorry, you're right. I originally interpreted your post as indicating that `let` statements use lexical binding by default, but now I see that lexical binding has to be turned on for the buffer in order for this to work.

Answer (score 0):

I don't use Spacemacs.  Does this do what you want?

```lisp
(defun bind-current-file ()
  `(spacemacs/set-leader-keys "of" (lambda ()
                                     (interactive)
                                     (find-file ,(buffer-file-name)))))
```